# Missing CloudFront entries for Lambda functions within Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

My client has entries within Route 53 that point to CloudFront endpoints.

These work (both the Route 53 entry and the CloudFront end point), but they don't exist in the CloudFront dashboard.

I have full admin access. I know the Route 53 entries point to Lambda functions. I've looked in ApiGateway, but they aren't documented there.

How or where do I define these? Do they exist in the background of AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in Custom Domains on your API Gateway

Comment: Yup, I just needed to scroll down the list of many, many things. Thanks Dave.